# How to write raw query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to write a raw query in Laravel Database: Query Builder, That outputs size of specific table

In core mysql query is as following

```
SELECT table_name "Name_of_the_table", table_rows "Rows Count", round(((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024),2)
"Table Size (MB)" FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "Name_of_the_Database" AND table_name ="Name_of_the_table";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get records by using raw query in laravel like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT table_name "Name_of_the_table", table_rows "Rows Count", round(((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024),2)
"Table Size (MB)" FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "Name_of_the_Database" AND table_name ="Name_of_the_table"';

$results = DB::select($sql);
```

Comment: Even you don't need to use DB::raw() to select by raw query. DB:select() will do everything for  you.

Comment: Use DB; //top of the controller and it's perfect. Thank, It takes few min to make it green :D  :D :D

Comment: Use DB; or you can use \DB::select($sql); as well.. Thanks its laravel's beauty brother

Answer (score 6):

You can use the query builder, since you can minimize the raw part to the table size:

```
$data = DB::table('information_schema.TABLES')
    ->where('table_schema', 'Name_of_the_Database')
    ->where('table_name', 'Name_of_the_table')
    ->select(
        'table_name as "Name_of_the_table"',
        'table_rows as "Rows Count"',
         DB::raw('round(((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024),2) as "Table Size (MB)"')
    )
    ->first();
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you! I've used this to get the number of rows for a very large table, when count errors. I'm just rephrasing the question so that it shows up when you search for that too ;-)